# Mars 4.5 crashes while trying to use the MMIO keyboard?

Tags: debugging, assembly, crash, mips, mars-simulator

I am making a game and am using the keyboard and display MMIO simulator to get the input from the player to move the character on screen but seemingly at random MARS itself will become completly unresponsive and has to be closed out by task manager.

I have tried changing my code around, I made sure to only check for input when the ready bit allows for it, I've tried steping through the program but it has never happened at anything less than full speed. Because of this I can never tell exactly whats causing it to crash since it won't break unless I run it at full speed but if I run it at full speed I can't see whats going on and can't go back and see what it was doing before it crashed. Any ideas on either what might be wrong or how I can find out whats wrong?